# How would I arrange for multiple cin with a sentinal value?

Tags: c++

This program should take in data from another file. This file has numbers like:

2017 3 12

4223

161 10.0 0 2 T

99 5.00 10 3 T

0

581

123 45.00 10  3 T

921 5.25 0 1 N

83 14.99 25 2 T

0

4223 and 581 are the receiptnum; 161, 99, 123, etc, are the item IDs; there are four other inputs after item ID which I will try to deal with later; 0 is sentinel.

What I tried is using a while loop to read the data, and if it's not the sentinel, to process and output item id at the least. Yet it doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double operation;
  int year; 
  int month;
  int day; 
  int receiptnum
  int itemid;
  double regprice; 
  int percentoff;  
  int numpurchased;
  char taxstatus; 

  cin >> year >> month >> day;
  cout << "Date of purchases: "  << month << "/" << day << "/" << year     << endl

  cin >> receiptnum >> itemid >> regprice >> percentoff >> numpurchased >> taxstatus;
  while(receiptnum && itemid && regprice && percentoff && numpurchased && taxstatus != '0')
  {
    //    cin >> itemid >> regprice >> percentoff >> numpurchased >> taxstatus;
    cout<< itemid << endl;
  }


 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using logic operators wrong. You have to compare each of them to 0 separately and use the `&&` operator on the results of the comparison.

```
while(thing1 != 0 && thing2 != 0)
```

The only thing that the `&&` operator does is take two bool values and return true if both operands are true. It can't do things like comparing a variable to multiple values or compare multiple values to the same variable.

Also, variables such as `recipenum` represent numbers, not characters. so you should compare them to `0` instead of `'0'`, which represents the character `0`, instead of the numerical value.

Comment: Should I add "char sentinel" to the variables list? And sentinel = 0 before the while loop?

Comment: The problem is that by using the quotes on `'0'`, you are comparing the *numbers* to the *character* 0, not the numerical value 0 (the number one less than 1). Just remove the quotes.

Comment: Variables such as `recipenum` store a *number*, not a *character*. It's important to be able to tell the difference. Weird stuff happens when you compare a number to a character. You're inputting into an int variable, so the `>>` operator will treat the input as a number. You should then compare the input to a number, not a character.